# return object get into a variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, codeigniter

I need to get object array into a variable which is return from controller,to the success function in the ajax function,I need to concatenate id to the site_url,

here is my code

**view**

```
<div id="abc"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>   //no need to specify the language
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#myForm1').on("submit",function(e) {

            //var form = $(this);
            //dataString = $("#myForm1").serialize();
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('form_controller/insert_into_db'); ?>",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                //dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){
                   // top.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('form_controller/callform'); ?>";
                    //$.each(data.results, function(){
                   // $("#abc").append('<div><b>' + id.id + '</b></div><hr />');

                    //});
                    /*var site_url = "<?php// echo site_url('form_controller/callform/') ?>";
                    site_url = site_url +"/" + id;
                    $("#abc").load(site_url);*/
                    <?php //foreach(): ?>

                    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('form_controller/callform'); ?>";
                    var mydata=window.JSON.stringify(data.trim());


                    site_url = site_url +"/" + "mydata" ;
                    //alert(mydata);
                     $("#abc").load(site_url);
                    $('#abc').html(data);
                    alert(data);

                }//,
                //error: function() { alert("Error posting feed."); }
           });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

**here is my alert output**

here I need to concatenate data as `id` for the site_url. here is my alert

```
[{"id":"215"}]
```

I need to get this as :

`var id=215;`

Comment: `var id = data.id;` quite simply

Comment: @ljacqu it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery for a parse JSON.

```
...
 success: function(data){
                  ...
                    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url('form_controller/callform'); ?>";
                    var mydata=window.JSON.stringify(data.trim());

                    var jobj=jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText); //<---JSON to object
                    site_url = site_url +"/" + jobj.id ; //<--- jobj.id - your id
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `datatype` to "json" and use `data.id`

**dataType**

```
Type: String
The type of data expected from the server. 
Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
```